# Interpreting iOS code to get Bluetooth Low Energy data on Android

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was sent iOS C code to get data from a Bluetooth Low Energy scale and I need to find out how to create similar functions into Android Java code.

The scale I am working with aren't using typical UUIDs and formatting.

I already have a scanner set up with the ability to write and listen to notifications.

What I need to do is figure out how to get the weight data.

I know is that 0XFFF0 is the service UUID, 0XFFF1 is the write characteristic and 0XFFF4 is the notify characteristic.

I'm guessing it writes something, then the scale gives you the data. But I'm not sure what.

Plus I think the scale sends the data with NSUTF8StringEncoding if I'm reading it correctly. How would I implement this on Java?

Here is the code sent to me:

http://www.anj.fyi/BTManagerlib.m (I tried to post the code here, but it's registering as spam for some odd reason)

I really appreciate the help guys.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"The scale I am working with aren't using typical UUIDs and formatting."

Yes, it uses, except it is written in [16-bit format](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/16-bit-uuids-for-members) If you want 128-bit UUID use XXXXYYYY-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB base to create it.

From the example that you have posted:

```
-(void)writeDataToBlue:(NSNotification *)note
{
    id obj = [note object];
    _senddata = obj;
    [self sendBlueToothData:_senddata showAlert:YES];
}
```

it is clear that data to be written to the device are not bundled into the source code, but they are received via notification center, from some other class. Ask them for device documentation or full source code, otherwise you won't be able to make any conclusions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate.